# jQuery toggleClass() navigation not working

Tags: jquery, navigation, toggleclass

Here is my markup: http://jsfiddle.net/dF2bM/2/

```
.active
{
    background: #f4b436;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 85px;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

.active class should provide a yellow bg to the "li" selected on click, but it doesn't work.

I loosing my hope, so I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });// <== You are missing this line
});
```

here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dF2bM/5/)

Comment: I can't belive it, took me 20 minutes! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Your script had syntactical errors, a closing bracket was missing `});`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gDmWY/)

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your code,

you are missing `});` in `li.Click()`

Change your code like below...

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/dF2bM/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li a').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```